# using Java custom operator within java API in infosphere streams

Tags: infosphere-spl, ibm-infosphere

I have been searching for awhile now on how to use a customized Java operator withing infosphere streams Java API

What I need is after writing a customized operator like below ...

```
public class Test extends AbstractOperator {
private int i;
private int num;
@Override
public synchronized void initialize(OperatorContext context) throws Exception {
super.initialize(context);
i = 0; ....
```

I want to use it like the below ....

```
        Topology topology = new Topology("toplogy_test");
        TStream<String> inDataFileName = ...
//call the "Test" operator here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a Java operator / C++ operator from the topology API by doing the following:

1. Add the toolkit of the Java operator:

   SPL.addToolkit(topology, new File("/home/streamsadmin/myTk"));
2. Convert the incoming stream to SPL stream:

   ```
   StreamSchema rstringSchema = Type.Factory.getStreamSchema("tuple<rstring rstring_attr_name>");

   SPLStream splInputStream = SPLStreams.convertStream(inDataFileName, new BiFunction<String, OutputTuple, OutputTuple>(){

     @Override
     public OutputTuple apply(String input_string, OutputTuple output_rstring) {
       output_rstring.setString("rstring_attr_name", input_string);
       return output_rstring;
     }}, rstringSchema);
   ```
3. Invoke the operator:

   SPLStream splOutputStream = SPL.invokeOperator("OperatorNamespace::YourOperatorName", splInputStream, rstringSchema, new HashMap());

You can find more information about this here:

http://ibmstreams.github.io/streamsx.documentation/docs/4.2/java/java-appapi-devguide/#integrating-spl-operators-with-the-java-application-api

On a side note, if you are thinking about using the Topology API to write the Streams topology, then it's easier to write a regular Java class, and invoke it directly from the Topology API.

For example:

```
MyJavaCode someObj = new MyJavaCode();

Topology topology = new Topology("MyTopology");
TStream<String> inDataFileName = ...
inDataFileName.transform(new Function<String, String>(){
        @Override
        public String apply(String word) {
            return someObj.someFunction(word);
        }
    });
```

The only requirement here is that your Java class needs to implement Serializable.

Comment: someObj.someFunction(word) , can this function be a webservice call or JDBC insertion call ?

Comment: Yes, the function can do anything.  I have taken this approach and wrappered GSON library to do streaming JSON parsing with the Topology API.  The key thing is make sure that the class is Serializable and the objects being passed back to the topology API are also serializable.